# Android app crashes when try to navigate from one screen to other

Tags: android, crash, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-transitions

Android jetpack compose app crashes when try to navigate from one screen to other with navArguments.
Below is my code to navigate to the detail screen.

I tried to pass via navArguments but didn't succeed. I've metioned the data that I tried to pass from listing to detail screen.

Successful navigation : contact_list_detail_screen/contact={"name":"Salman","number":"+923218888888","type":"Mobile"}

Failed navigation : contact_list_detail_screen/contact={"name":"COAS","number":"03219999999","picture":"content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/216","type":"Mobile"}

Source:

```
ContactItem(contact) {
                    val contactStr = GsonBuilder().create().toJson(contact).toString()
                    Log.d(
                        "contact_path",
                        ScreenRoutes.ContactDetail.route.replace("{contact}", contactStr)
                    )
                    navController.navigate(
                        ScreenRoutes.ContactDetail.route.replace("{contact}", contactStr)
                    )
                }
```

Navgraph:

```
  composable(route = Screen.ContactDetail.route,
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Companion.Left,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            },
            popExitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Companion.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            }) { navStack ->
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ContactViewModel>()
            val contactString = navStack.arguments?.getString("contact")
            val contact = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(contactString, Contact::class.java)
            ContactDetailScreen(navController, viewModel, contact)
        }
```

and here is my Contact model:

```
data class Contact(
    val name: String = "NA",
    val number: String = "NA",
    val picture: String?,
    val type: String = "NA"
)
```

Comment: if app is crashing then you have some exception stacktrace in logcat, post it